# What is the best key remapper tool?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, keyboard, mapping

I use international keyboards which have <kbd>`</kbd> (<kbd>~</kbd> with shift) next to <kbd>Z</kbd> key. I'm used to having <kbd>`/~</kbd> key next to <kbd>1</kbd> (currently, this key produces <kbd>§</kbd> or <kbd>±</kbd> with shift, which I don't use at all). My goal is to remap <kbd>§/±</kbd> key to <kbd>`/~</kbd>.

I have found several key remapping tools for Mac OS, so I want to ask which one do you have best experience with. (I use Mac OS X 10.6)

Comment: http://xahlee.info/kbd/Mac_OS_X_keymapping_keybinding_tools.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

great question... I've been looking for a tool that will allow me to emulate TouchCursor for Windows on the mac for a long time.  Tried **[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)**, **DoubleCommand**, and some others that I can't remember right now :)  KeyRemap4Macbook seemed to be closest to what I needed, but I could never get around to configuring it how I wanted it.  Your mileage may vary.

Check out [this page](http://alternativeto.net/software/keyremap4macbook/) that gives some of the aforementioned programs and start playing :)

Comment: Neither Ukelele nor KeyRemap4Macbook seem able to do this, but they are both great programs for the other tasks involved in having weird keyboards.

Comment: Thanks. I use KeyRemap4Macbook for mapping paragraph sign to `/~ and so far it works great for me. No crashes :-)

Comment: @Peter: glad it worked for you!  I need to spend some more time with it because I need to extend it in order to have it do what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.